# Why does cucumber run @Before in all glue code files

Tags: java, junit, cucumber-jvm

I have a problem with my cucumber tests. It runs the `@Before` method in 
all the glue classes.

For example. This feature file have one glue code in the `MainStepDef.class`.

```
#language: en
@run
Feature: Testing a feature
  Test before method

  Background: 
    Given stuff is created

  Scenario: The test
    When i do stuff
    Then stuff will be done
```

The `MainStepDef`:

```
public class MainStepDef {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        System.out.println("This is OK!");
    }

    @Given("^stuff is created$")
    public void stuff_is_created() throws Throwable {
    }

    @When("^i do stuff$")
    public void i_do_stuff() throws Throwable {
    }

    @Then("^stuff will be done$")
    public void stuff_will_be_done() throws Throwable {
    }

}
```

I have an additional glue file called: `OtherStep.class`

```
public class OtherStepDef {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        throw new RuntimeException("No! Bad code! BAD CODE!");
    }

    @Given("^some other stuff is also created$")
    public void some_other_stuff_is_also_created() throws Throwable {
    }
}
```

And finally I have my runner class.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(strict = true, tags = {"@run", "~@ignore" }, 
        format = {"html:target/systemtest", "pretty" }, features = "classpath:features/",
        glue = {"com.sorkmos.stepdef" }, monochrome = true)
public class RunFeatures {

}
```

When I run this I get the runtime exception from the `OtherStepDef` setup method.

Why does this happen? Should it not execute only the glue needed for the feature?

Example project:
https://github.com/cannibalcow/cucumberproblem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour of Cucumber: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cukes/7gILvMsE2Js

> This is the intended behaviour of the @Before and @After hooks: they
>   are not related to each step definition. Every hook is run on each
>   scenario (unless it's filtered out by tags).

Comment: Solved my problem by grouping the glue "before" methods with tags and then adding the depending tags to the featurefiles. Got 50% better performance. :)